# Cant get these divs to display inline?

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to figure out how to get these divs to display on the same line. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
.pos-sts {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: slategray;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="pos-sts">
  <h3>Items in Position/Block</h3>
</div>
<div class="pos-sts">
  <h3>Items Trained During Eval Period</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Create a parent `div` element and then set CSS property `display:flex;`

Answer (score -2):

The `<div>`'s arn't next to each other because there's no room.

2x `50%` is to much to be placed next to each other.

Consider changing the width to eg `49%`

```css
.pos-sts {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: slategray;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    width: 49%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="pos-sts">
  <h3>Items in Position/Block</h3>
</div>
<div class="pos-sts">
  <h3>Items Trained During Eval Period</h3>
</div>
```

---

Or, use [flex](/questions/tagged/flex) so you don't have to worry about the width:

```css
.pos-sts {
    background-color: slategray;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
 }
 
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="pos-sts">
    <h3>Items in Position/Block</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="pos-sts">
    <h3>Items Trained During Eval Period</h3>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: That 49% trick is great as well! Gives what I'm doing a much more clean and professional look. Thank you!

Comment: Hello @0stone0 how  you get all stackoverflow guidline urls ?

Comment: @AnkitTiwari You can find most of those presets [on this markdown faq page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Answer (score -2):

I used `display:inline;` and `float:left` and it worked just how I needed it to!

Comment: The other answer doesn't suggest `float:left`. Accepting it instead of posting what works seems... counterintuitive here.